# Black Screen at time of launching app

Tags: android

I am getting black screen with application name at the time of launching application over the first activity how to resolve it please suggest me..

```
        I am getting black screen with application name at the time of launching application over the first activity how to resolve it please suggest me..
```

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ctx = this;
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


Intent i = getIntent();
if (null == i || null == i.getExtras() ||
    !i.getExtras().containsKey("levels")) {

  activityCustomStarted = false;
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mGameView = (DroidGameView)findViewById(R.id.game);
} else {

  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(
      FrozenDroid.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int startingLevel = sp.getInt("levelCustom", 0);
  int startingLevelIntent = i.getIntExtra("startingLevel", -2);
  startingLevel = (startingLevelIntent == -2) ?
                  startingLevel : startingLevelIntent;
  activityCustomStarted = true;
  mGameView = new DroidGameView(this, i.getExtras().getByteArray("levels"),
                           startingLevel);
  setContentView(mGameView);
}

mGameThread = mGameView.getThread();

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  mGameThread.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
mGameView.requestFocus();

setFullscreen();
```

}

xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.shagunstudio.bubbleshoot.DroidGameView
android:id="@+id/game"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

activity in menifest

```
<activity
android:name="com.shagunstudio.bubbleshoot.FrozenDroid"
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"`enter code here`
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.FrozenDroid" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android``:name="com.shagunstudio.bubbleshoot.GAME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Please paste your code here so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() methods in your code, you might be doing some time consuming, blocking tasks. Load heavy background tasks on a separate thread.

Profile your code with [Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to check what is taking more time.